# Android Studio could not find, download, attach code sources

Tags: android, android-studio, android-workmanager

I wanted to see CoroutineWorker (`androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.2.0`) class code sources, but android studio (tried on versions: 4.1.3 and smaller) show decompiled version of that:
[image: no sources]
When I click download sources Gradle shows such error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script '/tmp/ijmiscinit4.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:DownloadSources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:downloadSources_2108a026-03c6-4d30-a902-3a53b9d5d155'.
   > Could not find androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.2.0@aar.
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Could you please help what I am doing wrong here?

Second issue: even if sources are downloaded, AndroidStudio still won't attach them, [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/mpdtl0/could_anyone_view_the_sources_of_thirdparty/) I've described that issue in detail.

Comment: make sure to have android sources version and emulator android sdk version is the same (for example both should be 33 API version)